# HTML dropdown box mouseover

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I know how to make a standard drop down box, however I want it to show the options on a however, and if someone clicks on the button, it opens a page, not opens the below links.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try the onHover and onChange events

You can start research on this task by evaluating the `onHover` and `onChange` events of the relevant control.

Provide more context for the question if you have an opportunity, and we will try to provide more specifics if you have difficulty.

Thanks for your participation on the site.

Comment: Great @GiacomoLawrance! If you do not need any additional assistance feel free to mark the answer as accepted if you like. Thanks again for participating on StackOverflow!